# What exactly does "efficiency" mean in XFLR5 wing analysis?

Tags: aircraft-design, efficiency, software

Can somebody please tell me what it is / how is it calculated?

[image]

I initially thought it might be something with the Cl/Cd but I have another design with close to the same Cl/Cd, but with more than double the efficiency (more than 1.0)

Comment: Try various angles of attack up to stall.  Your data shows AoA of 0 degrees.  Go higher AoA.  CL/CD may improve.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni it does, but that does not answer my question

Comment: Could it be [Oswald](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oswald_efficiency_number) efficiency?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni: I also think it is the Oswald coefficient aka efficiency factor. @ Vincent can you plot the spanwise lift distribution?